# How to convert downloaded Zinio publications to an open format?

Tags: linux, compatibility, ebook

I got a free temporary subscription to PC Magazine on [Zinio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinio) and I liked it. Now I'm considering renewing the subscription and looking at other interesting publications they may have, but that's conditional to the following?

- Can publications be read offline?
- From Linux?
- Can the document files be converted to an open format like PDF or ODF?

Items 1 and 2 got a thumbs up already. The offline Linux reader, from what I can see, even works as well as the Windows one. Now comes the $64,000 question: can I convert them to a format that doesn't depend on their proprietary reader?

The reader can be downloaded [here](http://beta.zinio.com/www/apps/desktop.jsp). Free sample magazines can be obtained [here](http://www.zinio.com/browse/publications/free-samples.jsp). (You will have to register with an e-mail.)

I couldn't even figure out where the downloaded issues reside in the filesystem. In my CentOS 6 machine, it created a directory named `~/.appdata/ZinioReader4.(FORTY-DIGIT-HEX-NUMBER).1/` but I can't make sense of its subfolders.

Answer (score -1):

I know this comes quite late, but anyway:

1. If you have a 64 bit distro, make sure you can execute 32 bits binaries.
2. Download & install the AIR reader for Linux (discontinued as of today, but you can install an old version).
3. Download & install the Zinio reader.

This works quite well for me.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Just as a small comment, the asker seems to have solved the "reading" problem. The question is primarily about converting to an open format (which this answer unfortunately doesn't seem to address, unless I am missing something?).